# Add spaces at the beginning of the print output in python

Tags: python, format, f-string

I'm wondering how Am I suppose to add 4 spaces at the beginnings of the print outputs with f-string or format in python?

This is what I use to print now:

```py
print('{:<10}'.format('Constant'),'{:{width}.{prec}f}'.format(122, width=10, prec=3))
```

and my output look like this:

```
Constant     122.000
```

but what I want is to have 4 spaces before the constant in the output like:

```
( 4 spaces here )Constant     122.000
```

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `print('    {:<10}'.format('Constant'), ...` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of operating system will be used to run my code. if I simply add 4 spaces at the beginning will the Linux and Windows run the same result with my code? @Matthias

Comment: A space should be a space as far as python printing is concerned regardless of operating system I think @AndrewSwainskeren

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you could do it:

1. If `Constant` is really an unchanging constant, why not just

   ```py
   print(f"    {Constant}", ...)
   ```

   before your other string?
2. With your current implementation, you are *left-aligning* to a width of 10 characters. If you swap that to *right-align*, like `'{:>12}'.format('Constant')` ("Constant" is 8 characters, 12 - 8 = 4 spaces) It will put 4 characters in front of the string.

Here's a Python f-string syntax cheat sheet I've used before:

https://myshell.co.uk/blog/2018/11/python-f-string-formatting-cheatsheet/

And the official docs: [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'  ' + string` *(as suggested)*,  but a more robust approach could be:

```
string="Test String leading space to be added"
spaces_to_add = 4
string_length=len(string) + spaces_to_add     # will be adding 4 extra spaces

string_revised=string.rjust(string_length)
```

result:

```
'    Test String leading space to be added'
```